# How to convert nested list into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a nested list looked liek this:

```
[[{'aaa': '42'}, {'bbb': '60'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '14'}, {'eee': '15'}, {'eee': '84'}],
 [{'aaa': '4'}, {'bbb': '0'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '1'}, {'eee': '1'}, {'eee': '8'}]]
```

And I want to convert it into a Dataframe.
I looked at many solutions on our portal but nothing works for me :(
Please help me as I'm a fresher in Python and Pandas module. Thank you!

Here is my desired Output:

[image]

I'm doing something like this but it's not working for me:
DataFrame(data_dicts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `L` your input list, you can use a list/dictionary comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{k:v for d in l for d in l for k,v in d.items()} for l in L])
```

*NB. note that you have duplicated keys in your dictionaries, the **last** ones take precedence*

output:

```
  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
0  42  60  25  14  84
1   4   0  25   1   8
```

input:

```
L = [[{'aaa': '42'}, {'bbb': '60'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '14'}, {'eee': '15'}, {'eee': '84'}],
     [{'aaa': '4'}, {'bbb': '0'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '1'}, {'eee': '1'}, {'eee': '8'}]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway, it's working exactly the way I want. Learned something today!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict` to collect all values of a key together and then use `pd.concat` to construct a dataframe  -

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lld = [[{'aaa': '42'}, {'bbb': '60'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '14'}, {'eee': '15'}, {'eee': '84'}],
 [{'aaa': '4'}, {'bbb': '0'}, {'ccc': '25'}, {'ddd': '1'}, {'eee': '1'}, {'eee': '8'}]]

d = defaultdict(list)
for sublist in lld:
    for subdict in sublist:
        for k, v in subdict.items():
            d[k].append(v)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(value, columns=[key]) for key, value in d.items()], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd eee
0   42   60   25   14  15
1    4    0   25    1  84
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   8
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mortz, it's working exactly the way I want. Learned something today!!